# No trace file for WCF client program

Tags: .net, wcf, diagnostics

I have a self hosted WCF service and a WCF Client (Web reference) that is using it.
When i add the diagnostics and service model config for tracing to the server side, it works perfectly and i see everything.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
       <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="EventsQueueMaxTester.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <EventsQueueMaxTester.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="EventsQueueMaxTester_clsapievents_CLSAPIEventsPollingService3" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://nim15166.nice.com:8002/CLSAPIEvents3</value>
      </setting>
    </EventsQueueMaxTester.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Information">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messagelistener"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                      initializeData="d:\myMessages.svclog"></add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
       propagateActivity="false">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                      initializeData="d:\myMessages.svclog"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>

    </sources>
    <trace autoflush ="true" />
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="d:\myMessages.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="xml" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true"
                      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                      logMalformedMessages="true"
                      maxMessagesToLog="5000"
                      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000">
      </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If it works perfectly, what is the problem?

Comment: If the config you're showing there is in the web.config file, try moving it to the app.config file. When you're self-hosting a service, the configuration needs to be in the config file associated with your DLL or Exe.